# How to install Snappy for Python 3?

Tags: python, snappy

Is this correct process for installing Snappy to use with Python?

```
wget url_to_download_snappy; 
tar xf snappy-x.y.z.tar.gz; 
cd snappy-x.y.z; 
./configure; 
make install; 
pip install python-snappy
```

If so - what is the 'latest' URL for downloading using WGET (from here `http://google.github.io/snappy/`)?

Comment: Is pip for python3? See `pip --version`.

Comment: pip --version
```pip 19.0.3```

Comment: python 2.7 or python 3

Comment: Try https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy

Comment: This is for Python 3.